# How to send a keystroke to an application with no window

Tags: c#

I'm trying to send a single keystroke to an application that has no window (because I have launched it with StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True) and therefore I can't use SendKeys. I had a look at SendMessage but this doesn't seem to be quite right as the programme I'm sending it to doesn't process message queues.

I would usually use the StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput property and send it via a StreamWriter but this doesn't not work as the application it is being sent to is looking for actual keyboard keystrokes, rather than pulling info from StandardInput (an old C++ programme using getch). Anyone have any ideas how to send a keystoke to an application with no window.

Answer (score 0):

There is a a pretty useful library I have used in the past. It may be of use to you, or at the very least, point you in the right direction.

[InputManager](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117657/InputManager-library-Track-user-input-and-simulate)